# syntax error while writing sentence using xmldom

Tags: xml, xmldom

I want to achieve the below output using xmldom

```
<ENVELOPE>
<LEDGER NAME="Shah" Action="CREATE">
</LEDGER>
</ENVELOPE>
```

for this how can i write 2nd line using xmldom?

Comment: That is not valid XML, the `<LEDGER>` tag is not closed. I think you want `<LEDGER NAME="Shah" Action="CREATE" />`.

Comment: i just cut and paste few lines from my code so it is their and how to write using xmldom in php.. not simple xml tree format.

Comment: @UmangShah: Thanks for coming back to post the answer! That's _exactly_ the right thing to do. :-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thaks for your appreciation.

Answer (score 3):

Need To Set Attributes for it..

```
$ledger = $xml->createElement("LEDGER");
$ledger->setAttribute("NAME", "$resul");
$ledger->setAttribute("Action", "CREATE");
```